# How To Create Scrolling Menu in Xna?

Tags: xna

How To Create Scrolling Menu in Xna like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ijambOyBgPg#t=25s

Comment: -1; There are many, many ways to do so. It's up to you to try finding or developing one that best works with your project.

Comment: Search google for scrolling menu tutorials... There will be a few on there. Although they will be in a different language, you can easily use your knowledge of XNA to convert the code to your preferred language :)

Comment: Yes, Scrolling menu with scalling text!

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want a scrolling menu, or is the text zooming necessary as well?

Xna doesn't support freely scaling fonts, as the size is defined at compile time, so if you need the zoom I suggest you either make the menu items as textures, and scale them based on how close they are to the center of the menu or write the text for each item on a RenderTarget2D, which you can then use as a texture.